# monodevelop crashing on startup on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, monodevelop

I have installed monoDevelop (2.4) from http://badgerports.org/ on my Linux box running Ubuntu 10.0.4

When I start monoDevelop from either the menu, or attempt to open a .cs file (or project), I see that monoDevelop starts (the mouse cursor changes shape etc), BUT after a few seconds, monoDevelop quits.

**[Edit]**

Here is the stack trace when I run monodevelop at the CLI:

> morpheous@somebox:~/work$ monodevelop 
>   WARNING: Cannot find Mozilla directory
>   containing libgtkembedmoz.so. Some
>   Addins may not be able to function.
>   Please set MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to your
>   Mozilla directory.
>
> ** (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe:2651):
>   WARNING **: The following assembly
>   referenced from
>   /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Core.dll
>   could not be loaded:
>        Assembly:   Mono.Addins.Setup    (assemblyref_index=9)
>        Version:    0.4.0.0
>        Public Key: 0738eb9f132ed756 The assembly was not found in the Global
>   Assembly Cache, a path listed in the
>   MONO_PATH environment variable, or in
>   the location of the executing assembly
>   (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/).
>
> ** (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe:2651):
>   WARNING **: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Mono.Addins.Setup,
>   Version=0.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or
>   one of its dependencies.
>
> ** (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe:2651):
>   WARNING **: The following assembly
>   referenced from
>   /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Ide.dll
>   could not be loaded:
>        Assembly:   glib-sharp    (assemblyref_index=5)
>        Version:    2.12.0.0
>        Public Key: 35e10195dab3c99f The assembly was not found in the Global
>   Assembly Cache, a path listed in the
>   MONO_PATH environment variable, or in
>   the location of the executing assembly
>   (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/).
>
> ** (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe:2651):
>   WARNING **: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'glib-sharp,
>   Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or
>   one of its dependencies.
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: A type load
>   exception has occurred.
>   morpheous@somebox:~/work$

Has anyone managed to get monoDevelop to run on Ubuntu 10.0.4?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try to run it from the commandline and see if it spews anything useful... (error messages etc.).

Comment: seems like he's missing the package for `glib-sharp`. Try to install it, and if it is installed mail a report to the repository maintainer.